# bind after unbind window Jquery

Tags: jquery, bind, unbind

I'm creating a page with two section where I load content `.load()` into `#container` by clicking on the titles.

```
<div id=dogs>[dogs]</div> 
<div id=cats>[cats]</div>
<div id=#container></div>
<div class=button_dogs></div>
```

**My problem**

I have a right-bottom fixed button that I only want it to be displayed in the section `#dogs` section (not in the cat section), and the page initializes by default with `#dog` section, so my code is something like that

```
$("#container").load("content.php?s=dogs"); //initial

$("#cats").click(){function(){
      $("#container").load("content.php?s=cats"); //after click
      $(".button_dogs").hide();
      $(window).unbind(".button");
}}

$("#dogs").click(){function(){
      $("#container").load("content.php?s=dogs"); //after click
      $(".button_dogs").show(); 
      $(window).bind("scroll.button");

}}
```

This is the fixed button binded to `window`

```
$(".button_dogs").hide();
$(window).bind("scroll.button", function(){
      if($(this).scrollTop()>50) {
          $(".button_dogs").show()
      } else {
          $(".button_dogs").fadeOut()
      }
});
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, When clicking on `#dogs` it binds again the fixed button function, but it doesn't work with the effects of before.This is the line I have doubts about (from #dogs click event)

```
$(".button_dogs").show();   
$(window).bind("scroll.button");
```

Comment: In the three lines of HTML you posted here, you have at least two errors

Comment: everything woks besides the .bind() to resotre the scroll funciton, upated the so important html tags...

Comment: @myfunkyside Why not explain that they should be wrapping element IDs and classes in quotes, rather than just say *"there are errors"*?  Not helpful.

Comment: I'd focus on your HTML before even thinking about JS/jQuery `<div id="dogs">[dogs]</div><div id="cats">[cats]</div><div id="container"></div><div class="button_dogs"></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to wrap the element IDs and classes with quotes.  Some browsers don't care but others do.  Also, don't prefix the container ID with a hash unless you're using a selector to find it...

```
<div id="dogs">[dogs]</div> 
<div id="cats">[cats]</div>
<div id="container"></div>
<div class="button_dogs"></div>
```

You can do what you're trying to do without removing and re-adding the event handler function.  This method will use a data attribute on the content div to specify what the content type is, so the scroll handler can simply exit if it's not dog content...

```
// keep a reference to the content div, rather than keep looking it up...
var $container = $("#container");

$("#cats").click(function() {
    $container
        .load("content.php?s=cats")
        .data("content", "cats");       // add a data attribute that has the value "cats"
});

$("#dogs").click(function() {
    $container
        .load("content.php?s=dogs")
        .data("content", "dogs");       // add a data attribute that has the value "dogs"
});

$(".button_dogs").hide();

$(window).bind("scroll.button", function() {
    // if the content is not dogs then exit this function...
    if ($container.data("content") != "dogs") return;

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $(".button_dogs").show();
    }
    else {
        $(".button_dogs").fadeOut();
    }
});

$("#dogs").trigger("click");  // click the dogs button to initialize the page
```

I also added the variable `$content` which is a reference to the `#content` element, so you don't need to keep looking it up every time you reference it.  Repeated lookups are not that expensive with an ID, but it's a good habit to get into.

Finally, I added code to click the dog button when the page loads, rather than have to duplicate the code that is executed when that happens.

Comment: ,I thought this problem was about binding and unbinding the scroll event. your tips are so helpful as well. Initializing with this is pretty clever `$("#dogs").trigger("click");` , I fixed the problem, thank you for your answer,

Comment: No problem - happy to help :)